# If $A_n=(n,\infty)\subset\mathbb R$, why, $m(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n)≠\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(A_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $A_n=(n,\infty)\subset\mathbb R$, why, $m(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n)≠\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(A_n)$

This should be a counter-example, that the equality doesn't hold, if we omit the assumption, that $m(A_k)<\infty$ for at least one $k$. But for me they're equal, both side zero.

Comment: Because $m(A_k)=\infty$ for all $k$, while $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\emptyset$.

Comment: @David Mitra Do you form disjoint sets or what? and is it wrong, that $\quad$ $m(\bigcap\limits_1^N A_n)=\lim\limits_{1\to N}m(A_n)$

Hence $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\Big(m(\bigcap\limits_1^N A_n)\Big)=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\Big(\lim\limits_{1\to N}m(A_n)\Big)$, ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. But, simply, the intersection of all the $A_n$ is the empty set. So the LHS of your inequality is $m(\emptyset)=0$. But on the RHS, each term, $m(A_n)$, in the limit is infinite, so the limit is infinite.

Comment: @DavidMitra This is a very ''dry explanation''. So you believe that, $\bigcap_1^\infty A_n=(\infty,\infty)=\emptyset$ ,but   $lim_{n\to\infty}m(A_n)≠m((\infty,\infty))=m(\emptyset)$ ?

Comment: There isn't much to say. $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\emptyset$: no real number belongs to every interval $(n,\infty)$.  On the other hand, the measure of any $A_n$ is $\infty$. So you have $m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=m(\emptyset)=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} m(A_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \infty=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to expand on  the comment by [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714428/if-a-n-n-infty-subset-mathbb-r-why-m-bigcap-limits-n-1-infty-a-n-l#comment1495068_714428). Focus on one part of formula at a time, and remember that the *order of operations* matters. To understand $m\left(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)$, read the formula inside out:

1. What is $A_n$? It's the interval $(n,\infty)$.
2. What is the intersection of all intervals $(n,\infty)$? It's the empty set, $\varnothing$.
3. What is the measure of $\varnothing$? It is zero.

So, $m\left(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)=0$.

To understand $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} m(A_n)$, read it inside out:

1. What is $A_n$? It's the interval $(n,\infty)$.
2. What is the measure of the interval $(n,\infty)$? It's infinite.
3. What is the limit of $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$? It is $\infty$ itself.